# Add ArrayList items to a new ArrayList comparing a value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList` (`invProperty`) which has two fields `invoice_no` and `invoice_qty`. I want to add items to a new `ArrayList` (`newProperty`) where `invoice_no` equals to a value (`invNumber`). I am checking with the first ArrayList. I have come up with two approaches and I want to know which one is better, or is there any other solutions?

`invProperty` is the first ArrayList and `newProperty` is the new ArrayList. `invNumber` is the value I am checking,

```
for (InvoiceSubData s : invProperty) {
    if (invNumber.equals(s.getInvoiceNo())) {
        newProperty.add(s);
    }
}

for (InvoiceSubData s : invProperty) {
    if (s.getInvoiceNo().contains(invNumber)) {
        newProperty.add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your expected result is the same in both cases, is more efficient the first one. The second one could match more times than first. Did you think in that?

Comment: I would prefer the more simple and imperative solution. Streams are fancy, but they include significant overhead for no real benefit when the filtering is this simple.

Comment: What is the type of `invNumber`?

Comment: It is a string.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your criteria you should use the first one. Second one could give you unwanted result.

For example: if your invoice number is "41235" and there is a invoice number in the list have "123" then it will generate true `("41235".contains("123"))` and added to your newly created list.

If you could use `Java 8` in your project you can also do this

```
newProperty = invProperty.stream()
                       .filter(item -> invNumber.equals(item.getInvoiceNo()))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just do that using java 8 streams:

```
List<InvoiceSubData> newProperty = invProperty.stream()
                .filter(x -> invNumber.equals(x.getInvoiceNo()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is for Android and my min API is 16

Comment: I think there isn't really any reason to use streams here. While streams are really fancy, new, and altogether better, this is not really a use-case where the benefits (being nonexistent) outweigh the small but existent stream overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are checking for equality, you need to use the first version (with the `.equals()`).

The second one is not correct, since it will return those that are subsets as well. E.g. `aaa.contains("a")` will return `true`, but is clearly not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda expression:

```
List<InvoiceSubData> newProperty = invProperty.stream().filter(x -> invNumber.equals(x.getInvoiceNo())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

This one eliminate one extra loop

```
    for (InvoiceSubData s : invProperty) {
            if (invNumber.equals(s.getInvoiceNo())) {
                newProperty.add(s);
                continue;
            }



            if (s.getInvoiceNo().contains(invNumber)) {
                newProperty.add(s);
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This would produce duplicates and fall into all the problems with the second `if` test.

Comment: continue jumps to next iteration

Comment: Yea, it would fall into the problems with the second `if` test.

Comment: first "continue" executes then it will start next iteration instead of going into second if statement